# JJB and Jenkins DSL plugin - advantages and disadvantages

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

We use JJB (Jenkins Job Builder) to generate our jobs, but recently I decided to try Jenkins DSL plugin as it is the same or close powerful as JJB, according to the information I have found. The reason to try another technology was that I wasn't able to solve one task with JJB. It made me dive into the DSL plugin technology, try to create jobs and organize everything in a way we have with JJB in order to understand if DSL plugin is better or worse, should we use it instead of JJB or maybe as a complementary.

It's not a lot of information in the Internet about advantages and disadvantages between theese two plugins, so I would like to ask you to help me to understand:

- what are advantages and disadvantages between JJB to Jenkins DSL plugin
- what tasks could be achieved with one and not with another?

From myself I can say the following things:
DSL plugin advantages:

1. DSL plugin allows us to use a power of programming language (groovy), which allows to create more effective job configurations.
2. DSL plugin doesn't depend on plugins developement - if there are new parameters and elements are added, you can easily add them using node syntax.
3. You can easily get variables from other DSL scripts using class import, for example (that's the reason I decided to try DSL plugin).

DSL plugin disadvantages:

1. It's more difficult to create templates with it, you need to add additional code to make it work. "using()" command doesn't allow you to pass variables.
2. Syntax is a bit more difficult.

Comment: You can use Groovy code to create templates (or builders / factories) for DSL scripts. Have a look at the [Job DSL Gradle example](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example), more specifically [GradleCiJobBuilder.groovy](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/dslexample/GradleCiJobBuilder.groovy). Another advantage is that you can use standard Groovy testing frameworks like Spock to test your configuration before committing any changes. See https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/dslexample.

Comment: Thank you, .text() method is really useful, I will use it in the future, I thought, that I can add only whole elements using with() command. And the testing framework is also a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

I am fans of JJB as well before, but it meets issues which stops me to work on it.

And when I noticed the out of jobDSL (2014.6?), it is right weapon for this task

Some issues:

1. Weak support for complex configuration: It is over Jenkins REST API, a lot of things can't be configured via external REST API. JobDSL is groovy based which can be used to get internal data from jenkins instance. With the powerful configure block, it can manipulate the config.xml if the normal DSL doesn't work.
2. Weak community: JobDSL is contributed from jenkins core developers and it was quickly supported by all users. And more and more plugins are supported directly by configuration.
3. Execution model: JJB is run over Jenkins API, while jobDSL is run inside jenkins jobs, which is easy for control.

Therefore I recommend to use JobDSL.

If your job is not so complex which JJB already support, and u r python fans, u can stay with it for sure.

Comment: accept it if you think it answers your question thx. Fine to keep it open for better answer. extra slides http://www.slideshare.net/larrycai/learn-jobdsl-for-jenkins

Comment: To me that JobDSL can only run inside the Jenkins is a limitation. As in my case I just want to create a job via command line. To use JobDSL I have to submit the dsl script to git repo and then trigger a seed job to create/update that job, I don't know if there is any workaround to allow me to create a job from a offline JobDSL script.